# Как сместить курсор в QLineEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, focus, qlineedit

Как сделать, чтобы курсор был около буквы 'T'? То есть автоматически он вставал на один символ правее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вводите `T` и курсор справа от него станет. Текущий `Title` это ведь setPlaceholderText?

Comment: Да, он самый. Что значит вводит "T"? Мне именно курсор нужно переместить.

Comment: Пытался установить курсор через setCursorPosition(1), чет не работает не с одной строкой.

Comment: У меня, просто используя стандартный qlineedit без стилей курсор стоит там где и должно быть. Возможно, у вас лишний пробел слева, или свой стиль добавил смещение placeholder'а или это стиль самой ОС, которое Qt использует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class CustomLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, text=None, text_holder=None, font_style="Arial", font_size=12, mode=0):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont(font_style, font_size))
        self.setText(text)
        self.setPlaceholderText(text_holder)
        self.setEchoMode(mode)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLineEdit{
                background: #fff;
                border: None;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        """)


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("""QWidget{background: #D0D3D8;}""")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.line_edit = CustomLineEdit(text_holder="Enter your Master Password", mode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

При вводе текста, курсор всегда будет стоять на второй позиции – после первого символа:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

app = Qt.QApplication([])

le = Qt.QLineEdit()
le.textEdited.connect(lambda text: le.setCursorPosition(1))
le.show()

app.exec()
```

---

При получении фокуса, line edit изменит позицию курсора на второй символ:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MyLineEdit(Qt.QLineEdit):
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        super().focusInEvent(event)

        self.setCursorPosition(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    le = MyLineEdit('Title')
    le.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при клике по строке курсор просто становился на 1 символ правее. И дальше как обычно следовал за набором текста.

Comment: А если подключить setCursorPosition(1) напрямую к самой строке, то почему-то вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov, это?

Comment: Оно самое. Тогда еще вопрос, если нажать на кнопку с стрелкой ' <-' на клавиатуре, то курсор передвигаться снова на 0 позицию. Как это исправить?

Comment: И не работает при установки setPlaceholderText().

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov, `И не работает при установки setPlaceholderText().` что не работает? Как placeholderText связан с курсором??

Comment: Строка всегда в фокусе. Я добавил 'le.setPlaceholderText(' Enter your Master Password')' и ничего.

Comment: Я добавил картинку в вопрос как должно получиться.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov Эммм, там ведь Placeholder так нарисовался, его позицию просто так не поменять

Comment: хотя смотрю в http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp?h=dev#n1962 и думаю, что кое-что попробовать можно

Answer (score 0):

Это оказалось проще, чем я думал) Может и выглядит колхозно, но за то работает как я хотел. Думаю, из примера видно, что я сделал.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

class QLabelClickable(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QLabelClickable, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(840, 581)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

class MyLineEdit(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Window = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.Window.setupUi(self)
        self.line_password = QLabelClickable(self.Window.centralwidget)
        self.line_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(286, 580/2-20, 200, 40)) # 890, 580
        self.line_password.setCursor(Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.line_password.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.line_password.clicked.connect(self.MylineEdit)
        self.line_password.setText('Enter your Master Password')
        self.line_password.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
            border: 1px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            color: #696969;
            font-size: 14px;
            }
            """)
        self.MylineE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.Window.centralwidget)
        self.MylineE.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(298, 275, 185, 30))
        self.MylineE.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.MylineE.setPlaceholderText('Enter your Master Password')
        self.MylineE.setStyleSheet("""
        QLineEdit {
            border: None;
            font-size: 14px;
            }
            """)
        self.MylineE.hide()
        self.line_password.show()

    def MylineEdit(self):
        self.MylineE.show()
        self.MylineE.setFocus()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.MylineE.clearFocus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MyLineEdit()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем 2 label'а и эта хитрая фигня с кликом и с hide/show?

Comment: Зачем так париться, если есть placeholder? https://pastebin.com/CWPbm8tg

Comment: placeholder возвращает курсор на 0 позицию.

Comment: Просто сдвинуть нормально курсор на 1 символ в право сложно. Поэтому я сделал кликабельный label, по которому по нажатии показывается lineEdit с фокусом, с placeholder и без всякого сдвига курсора. Можно и без hide/show в принципе.

Comment: Лааааадно, проехали. Я уже не хочу узнавать зачем такие такие танцы и чем стандартное поведение не нравится :)